# NAT gateway removal

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

There are some servers that are in private subnet and some are in public subnet.
I want to remove nat gateway and make all instances that were in private subnet to get access through internet gateway. Please suggest me the procedure.

When I have added internet gateway and removed Natgateway then started getting API timeout, please suggest me the possible reason for the same.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using AWS API Gateway, but requests are timing out? Is an associated AWS Lambda function being invoked?

Answer (score 2):

A "Public Subnet" is defined as a subnet that has a **Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway**.

Thus, if you want instances in the private subnet to have direct access to the Internet via the Internet Gateway, you will need to **convert the private subnet into a public subnet**. This can be done by adding a Route to the subnet's Route Table that directs traffic with a destination of `0.0.0.0/0` to the Internet Gateway.

Resources in the VPC that need to communicate with the Internet **will need to be assigned Public IP addresses**. This can be done for existing resources by **assigning an Elastic IP address** (which is a static IP address). However, there is a limit on the number of Elastic IP addresses available in each region.

Any new Amazon EC2 instances launched can be given a public IP address during launch, so they won't need an Elastic IP address.